# Sequence contains no elements mvc3 GoogleMaps.LocationServices

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc-3, google-maps

I have unusual problem. When I create an XML file with `XmlElement` in MVC3, I sometimes get this error (1 of 5 times)

> Sequence contains no elements
>
> [InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements]
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.First(IEnumerable`1 source) +336
>   GoogleMaps.LocationServices.GoogleLocationService.GetLatLongFromAddress(String
>   address) +185

In my controller I have this code:

```
using GoogleMaps.LocationServices;

public ActionResult Index()
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlDeclaration documentType = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null);
            doc.AppendChild(documentType);
            XmlElement markers = doc.CreateElement("markers");
            doc.AppendChild(markers);
            var locationService = new GoogleLocationService();
            foreach (var item in repository.Mreza.ToList())
            {
                XmlElement marker = doc.CreateElement("marker");

                XmlElement name = doc.CreateElement("name");
                XmlElement address = doc.CreateElement("address");
                XmlElement tel = doc.CreateElement("tel");
                XmlElement fax = doc.CreateElement("fax");
                XmlElement time2 = doc.CreateElement("time2");
                XmlElement more = doc.CreateElement("more");
                XmlElement lat = doc.CreateElement("lat");
                XmlElement lng = doc.CreateElement("lng");

                name.InnerText = item.Ime;
                address.InnerText = item.Ulica;
                tel.InnerText = item.Telefon;
                fax.InnerText = item.Fax;
                time2.InnerText = item.Email;
                more.InnerText = item.Web;

                var point = locationService.GetLatLongFromAddress(item.Grad);
                lat.InnerText = Convert.ToString(point.Latitude);
                lng.InnerText = Convert.ToString(point.Longitude);

                marker.AppendChild(name);
                marker.AppendChild(address);
                marker.AppendChild(tel);
                marker.AppendChild(fax);
                marker.AppendChild(time2);
                marker.AppendChild(more);
                marker.AppendChild(lat);
                marker.AppendChild(lng);

                markers.AppendChild(marker);
            }
            string URL = Server.MapPath("Content/NovoLayout/adreseXML.xml");
            doc.Save(URL);

            return View();
        }
```

Anyone knows what is wrong?

Comment: dont write if you dont know. bla,bla,bla is code for creating XML nodes and they are irrelevant.

Comment: And what is `locationService`? And what is the `GetLatLongFromAddress` method doing? And what is `item.Grad`? And how does the XML look like? You see how far are you from actually asking a real question? At least a question that would be a good fit for StackOverflow.

Comment: var locationService = new GoogleLocationService();

Comment: i put all my code....answer it now. my god dont be sarcastic if you dont know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How quickly are these xml files generated? The Google services all have request rate limits so you're likely coming up against this. Try imposing a wait between each call to the GoogleLocationService (100ms or so should do) and see if this fixes the issue.

Comment: thx. foreach is problem. i put delay 200ms on the end of loop and now is working. :)

Comment: No problem, the rate limits are not particularly well documented and so it often appears as an issue when using any Google API.

Comment: yeah...i cant find document for Google services anywhere on internet. i have another problem and maybe you can help me. When Google services cant find address (street) he trow me same error. how to put in Google services find lat,ltg by street if null by town etc.?

Comment: You're probably better starting a new question to attract more then just my attention, preferably with a code sample. The dev docs though are available here: https://developers.google.com/maps/