# Error : Sequence contains no elements

Tags: c#, google-maps

I got a error when i get lat and long using `locationService.GetLatLongFromAddress`

The error is  :

> *Sequence contains no elements*

I have tried this code

```
var locationService = new GoogleLocationService();
var points = locationService.GetLatLongFromAddress("Ram Theatre Bus Stop, Arcot Road, Vadapalani, Chennai, Tamil Nadu");
mapDetail.Latitude = points.Latitude;
mapDetail.Longitude = points.Longitude;
mapDetail.CollegeAddressId = addressDetail[i].CollegeAddressId;
```

What is the problem? How can i solve this?

Comment: Could you please post the code of the GoogleLocationService()? thanks

Comment: `GoogleLocationService` is a service class name from `GoogleMaps.LocationServices` dll

Comment: Relevant code -> https://github.com/sethwebster/GoogleMaps.LocationServices/blob/master/GoogleMaps.LocationServices/GoogleLocationService.cs

Comment: simple bug; I've submitted a pull request: https://github.com/sethwebster/GoogleMaps.LocationServices/pull/6

Comment: Guy's now i used " Thread.Sleep(200);" in my code. Now it's working. Why? I really confusing ..

Comment: @RameshRajendran that sounds unrelated. The method in question uses a synchronous `Load` method - your `Thread.Sleep` should have precisely no effect whatsoever. More likely: your repeated searching has caused the location to be indexed.

Comment: @MarcGravell , Yep Your correct, But it's working in my side, Very strange. I have tried that from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21260823/sequence-contains-no-elements-mvc3-googlemaps-locationservices?rq=1`

Comment: @RameshRajendran the library author has merged the pull request pushed the update; try updating

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would typically get that if code uses `.First()` or `.Single()` on a sequence (`IEnumerable<T>`) that has (as the message suggests): no elements. Meaning: an empty sequence (not to be confused with a `null` sequence). You don't show code that does that, so I can only assume this happens inside `.GetLatLongFromAddress()`. So it sounds like there is a bug, probably relating to the "not found" case, but in code that we can't see. Personally, I would expect the "not found" case to return a `null`, or to throw some explicit "not found" exception. If this bug is inside a library: tell the library authors about it. Or better: fix it, and submit a pull request (if you can).

Edit: [here we go](https://github.com/sethwebster/GoogleMaps.LocationServices/blob/master/GoogleMaps.LocationServices/GoogleLocationService.cs):

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(string.Format(APIUrlLatLongFromAddress,
    Uri.EscapeDataString(address)));
var els = doc.Descendants("result").Descendants("geometry")
    .Descendants("location").First();
if (null != els) {...}
```

IMO, that should be:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(string.Format(APIUrlLatLongFromAddress,
    Uri.EscapeDataString(address)));
var els = doc.Descendants("result").Descendants("geometry")
    .Descendants("location").FirstOrDefault();
if (null != els) {...}
```

One line code fix to send them...

Comment: +1 for it's helps me a another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23109558/24201-latitude-values-must-be-between-90-and-90-degrees?noredirect=1#comment35325381_23109558

Answer (score 2):

I've merged in Mark Gravell's pull request for the GoogleLocationService and have pushed an updated Nuget package.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/GoogleMaps.LocationServices/